# How can I stop the automatic creation of ~/.cache/motd.legal-displayed file?

Tags: home-directory, hidden-files

In every home-directory on my Ubuntu Server is a `.cache` folder containing an empty file `motd.legal-displayed`. Is there a way to stop creating these `.cache` folders?

Comment: I assume it is `motd.legal-displayed`?

Comment: The `.cache` folder in your home directory is used by lots of different things, so I wouldn't try to delete it unless I needed to free disk space. It's safe to delete it if you're willing to sacrifice performance. See the [XDG base directory specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `man update-motd` and `/etc/update-motd.d`

> Disable motd

See `/etc/pam.d/login` and comment out the line that has `session optional pam_motd.so` in it. You might also want to do this in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` if ssh is also a concern.

> Completely remove motd

This will remove anything related to motd (so also `motd.legal-displayed`):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge update-motd
```

Comment: I commented out these two lines and no more .cache folders were created. However, the complete removal of motd did not work.

Comment: @PascalGläser probably needed sudo in front of it (edited).

Comment: No that's not the problem I'm logged in as root. It says `Package update-motd is not installed, so not removed`.

Comment: Aha. Then it is weird you had that file and the config file on your system. Then again: the purge is not required anyways ;)

Comment: Yes it's weird! Thanks for your help, commenting out these lines solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, it seems the motd files now live inside another package instead. Package update-motd says `superceded by pam_motd in libpam-modules` and since whole libpam-modules can't be removed (?), to remove motd we have to remove the files manually:

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/security/pam_motd.so
```

and if you like:

```
/usr/share/man/man5/update-motd.5.gz  (libpam-modules)
/usr/share/man/man8/pam_motd.8.gz  (libpam-modules)
/usr/share/base-files/motd  (base-files)
/etc/update-motd.d/  (base-files)
/usr/share/man/man5/motd.5.gz  (manpages)
```